# How to traverse the dom tree of a website and get all the elements in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs, casperjs, dom-traversal

I'm new to web development and the task is to find all the elements on a webpage(For example, here I wanna to find all the elements on Amazon, including header, footer, navbar etc.), and then get the location and size of all of them.(Including height, width, top, bottom, left, right etc.) I try to use CasperJS and PhantomJS to do it, and here is my code:

```
casper.start('http://www.amazon.com/s?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=watches', function(){
});

var objarr = [];

casper.then(function(){
  var tmp = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]; //get the html and traverse all it children
  }
  traverseDOMTree(tmp);

  for (var i = 0; i < objarr.length; i++){
        var isvalid = judge(objarr[i]); //judge whether the elemnet is null.
        console.log(i+1);
        if (isvalid && i != 0) {
          console.log(objarr[i].textContent);
        }
  }
});

function traverseDOMTree(root) //traverse function
{
  if (root)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++){
        objarr.push(root.childNodes[i]);
        traverseDOMTree(root.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}

function judge(obj){ 
  if (obj == null) { 
    console.log("The object is NULL");
    return false;
  }
  //If it is not null, get its location and height with width
  console.log("___________________________");
  console.log("The offsetTop is ", obj.offsetTop);
  console.log("The offsetLeft is ", obj.offsetLeft);
  console.log("The height is", obj.clientHeight);
  console.log("The width is", obj.clientWidth);
}
```

So my method is first get the root of the DOM tree, which is `document.getElementsByTagId("html")[0]`. And then I traverse of all of its children and put all of the elements I find into an array. However, there are several problems here:

1. Most of the elements I find are null objects.
2. The traverse function seems only work on the same level and will not continue to traverse.
3. The CasperJS seems not stable to work, as I will get different problems/warning each time when I try to run.

I've debugged and tried different ways for a long time, but I still can't succeed. I guess I need to put my traverse function into the `casper.evaluate()`, but there is too little tutorial about how to use it on the web. So is there anyone can help me to find a feasible way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CasperJS, but maybe you can try `document.querySelectorAll("*")`.

Comment: That doesn't work. Most of the elements I get from this will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS and inherits some of it shortcomings like the two distinct contexts. You can only access the DOM (page context) through the sandboxed `casper.evaluate()` function. It cannot use variables that are defined outside and everything that you pass in or out has to be a primitive. DOM nodes are not primitives. See the docs ([`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

This means that you have to do everything inside of the page context, because you're directly working on those DOM nodes. You can pass the results out of the page context when you're done traversing.

Or you can simply move everything inside the page context and register to the "remote.message" event:

```
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    this.echo("remote> " + msg);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(function() {
        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]; //get the html and traverse all it children
        var objarr = [];

        traverseDOMTree(tmp);

        for (var i = 0; i < objarr.length; i++){
            var isvalid = judge(objarr[i]); //judge whether the elemnet is null.
            console.log(i+1);
            if (isvalid && i != 0) {
              console.log(objarr[i].textContent);
            }
        }

        function traverseDOMTree(root) //traverse function
        {
            if (root)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++){
                    objarr.push(root.childNodes[i]);
                    traverseDOMTree(root.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function judge(obj){ 
            if (obj == null) { 
                console.log("The object is NULL");
                return false;
            }
            //If it is not null, get its location and height with width
            console.log("___________________________");
            console.log("The offsetTop is ", obj.offsetTop);
            console.log("The offsetLeft is ", obj.offsetLeft);
            console.log("The height is", obj.clientHeight);
            console.log("The width is", obj.clientWidth);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You could reduce the amount of code a little by using the traverse function from the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is just getting all elements with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

But if you want to make it with recursion:

```js
function traverse(node, elems){
  if(node){
    elems.push(node)
    var childs = node.childNodes;
    for(var i=0;i<childs.length;i++){
      traverse(childs[i],elems)
    }
  }
}

domElements = []
traverse(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0], domElements)

console.log(domElements)
```

Comment: On this page: using first method, 1684 elements returned; using second method 3675 elements returned. Were these meant to produce the same result?

Comment: @thomas I think that´s because getElementsByTagName only picks elements with a tagname, so if in travserse function you change it to if(node && node.tagName){ it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simplest way to do this, and I am not sure if you are limited on how you can do this in some way, but I would just do this in plain javascript:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var element, index = 0, length = allElements.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    element = allElements[index];
    // get whatever information you want from the element
}
```

Comment: your loop would look better written as while (index++<length){}

Comment: Perhaps, but quite subjective in my opinion. Either way thanks for tip!! =]

Comment: I've tried it before but nearly all of the elements I get will be null. So I changed my way to traverse the whole dom tree from the root.

Comment: Thats odd. Seems like something else is going on if you are getting null elements. Are you sure whatever your code returns you is a string of html and not html elements themselves.

Comment: I think what I return should be html elements themselves. You can have a look at my judge function, which will return false if the element is null. And another wired things is when I use document.getElementsByTagName("*"), every time it will return different elements that are null or not null. I guess one of the reasons is casperjs didn't wait until the page is fully loaded to get all the elements. Anyway, I don't have clear idea about this.

Comment: Are you stuck with those libraries or can you use something else?